# MMQGIS plugin-merge problem

Tags: layers, merge, qgis-2.12

I work with 3 polygon layers (with the same CRS) from different data source each.

[image]

I try to merge those layers with MMQGIS plugin. The problem is that only 2 layers merged:

[image]

While i expected to get this result:

[image]
How can i solve this issue?

Comment: edit: moved here after suggestion

Do they have the same CRS? Is any layer in editing mode? If you try to merge the result of the 2 layers with the 3rd? Have u selected all the layers in the layer dialogue?

Comment: yes  they have they same CRS, no layer in edit mode, i selected all layers in the dialog box, no- i don't want to merge them separate.

Comment: Are you sure that even 2 layers were merged? the olive-green polygon overlaps the purple polygon, I've tested out a similar topology and layer order and the result puts the small polygon underneath the multipart one, meaning that it is not seen at all. Check to see of those parts are indeed included in the merge result, if not, you have a different issue here.

Comment: nope- those parts are indeed included in the merge result-it's ok- the problem is the third layer-it (the blue one) doesn't merged with the others layers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with a line layer. You might want to check if all layers, that are to be merged, have the same attributes AND if the attributes have the same dimensions.
e.g. if the attribute "Att_1" is in integer in your yellow layer and the same attribute "Att_1" is in integer 64 in your blue layer, the layers will not merge.

Comment: JB27 all the layers as the same attribute table with exact name fields.